# SPARQL error when Get all SuperClasses Of Class Until Root c#

Tags: c#, sparql, rdf, owl, protege

Hi i want to get all superClasses of subClass Until root, i use RDFDotNet , here is my code:

```
   string GetSuperClassesUntilRoot = @"
  PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
  PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
  PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX : <" + OntologyUrl + @">
  select ?superclass where {
  <" + Class+ @"> (rdfs:subClassOf|(owl:intersectionOf/rdf:rest*/rdf:first))* ?superclass .
  }
";
                string GetSuperClassesUntilRoot2 = @"
  PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
  PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
  PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX : <" + OntologyUrl + @">
  SELECT ?superClass WHERE
{ <" + Class + @"> rdfs:subClassOf* ?superClass .
}
";
 // FILTER (!isBlank(rdfs:subClassOf))
 //FILTER(!isBlank(?superClass))

                Object results = g.ExecuteQuery(GetSuperClassesUntilRoot2);

                if (results is SparqlResultSet)
                {
                    //SELECT/ASK queries give a SparqlResultSet
                    SparqlResultSet rset = (SparqlResultSet)results;

                    foreach (SparqlResult r in rset)
                    {

                        Classes.Add(r["superClass"].ToString());

                        //Do whatever you want with each Result
                    }

                }
                else if (results is IGraph)
                {
                    //CONSTRUCT/DESCRIBE queries give a IGraph
                    IGraph resGraph = (IGraph)results;
                    foreach (Triple t in resGraph.Triples)
                    {

                        //Do whatever you want with each Triple
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //If you don't get a SparqlResutlSet or IGraph something went wrong 
                    //but didn't throw an exception so you should handle it here
                    MessageBox.Show("No Data Found.");
                }
```

i try it with some owl file and it worked , but when i use another owl i get error :[image: Error Message]

the error message is :

```
Unable to Cast object of type 'VDS.RDF.Query.Patterns.FixedBlankNodePattern' to type 'VDS.RDF.Query.Patterns.NodeMatchPattern'
```

here is the owl file :
[OWL File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13PGhIQdgea2jdFUQAGeNf9ARKt4inVhs/view?usp=sharing)
I'm not sure but may this owl file made by Protege 5.5 because it is not open with Protege 4
 ,how fix this problem? please help me.
thanks for help

Comment: Dose any one have any idea of how to fixt this error?

Comment: ok, How to Get all SuperClasses Of Class Until Root ?

Comment: It looks like one of your classes is anonymous i.e. it doesn't have a URI but is a blank node.  When you try and substitute that back into a subsequent query it breaks because the query engine is not expecting a blank node where it encounters one.  Generally speaking trying to substitute blank nodes back into queries will rarely, if ever, give the expected results and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely better achieved just using APIs rather than trying to code it yourself with SPARQL.  See [Using the Ontology API](https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Ontology-API) from which we can adapt the first example like so:

```
// First create an OntologyGraph and load in some data
OntologyGraph g = new OntologyGraph();
// TODO: Load your data into the graph using whatever method is appropriate

// Get the class of interest
// TODO: Substitute the correct URI for your class of interest
OntologyClass someClass = g.CreateOntologyClass(new Uri("http://example.org/someClass"));

// Find Super Classes
foreach (OntologyClass c in someClass.SuperClasses)
{
  // TODO: Process the class as appropriate
}
```

Just fill in the TODOs with appropriate values for your application.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i found the problem which is in the class i send to get SuperlClasses, it is not correct , it must be Url#Lable  but it was not in this form , so this make error